# Perl Parsing CSV file with embedded commas

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, csv

I'm parsing a CSV file with embedded commas, and obviously, using split() has a few limitations due to this.

One thing I should note is that the values with embedded commas are surrounded by parentheses, double quotes, or both...

for example:

(Date, Notional),
"Date, Notional",
"(Date, Notional)"

Also, I'm trying to do this without using any modules for certain reasons I don't want to go into right now...

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need. It works in a very similar way to the code in [`Text::CSV_PP`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV_PP), but doesn't allow for escaped characters within the field as you say you have none

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $re = qr/(?| "\( ( [^()""]* ) \)" |  \( ( [^()]* ) \) |  " ( [^"]* ) " |  ( [^,]* ) ) , \s* /x;

my $line = '(Date, Notional 1), "Date, Notional 2", "(Date, Notional 3)"';

my @fields = "$line," =~ /$re/g;

say "<$_>" for @fields;
```

**output**

```
<Date, Notional 1>
<Date, Notional 2>
<Date, Notional 3>
```

---

**Update**

Here's a version for older Perls (prior to version 10) that don't have the regex branch reset construct. It produces identical output to the above

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $re = qr/(?: "\( ( [^()""]* ) \)" |  \( ( [^()]* ) \) |  " ( [^"]* ) " |  ( [^,]* ) ) , \s* /x;

my $line = '(Date, Notional 1), "Date, Notional 2", "(Date, Notional 3)"';

my @fields = grep defined, "$line," =~ /$re/g;

say "<$_>" for @fields;
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you already have a working solution with Borodin's answer, but for the record there is also a simple solution with split (see the results at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/q9Esr9)). This situation sounds very similar to [regex match a pattern unless...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$regex = '(?:\([^\)]*\)|"[^"]*")(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*,\s*';
$subject = '(Date, Notional), "Date, Notional", "(Date, Notional)"';
@splits = split($regex, $subject);
print "\n*** Splits ***\n";
foreach(@splits) { print "$_\n"; }
```

**How it Works**

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `(parentheses)` and `(quotes)`, then deliberately fails. The right side matches commas, and we know they are the right commas because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

**Possible Refinements**

If desired, the parenthess-matching portion could be made recursive to match `(nested(parens))`

**Reference**

[How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is quite old question, but for completeness I would like to add solution from great book "Mastering Regular Expressions" by Jeffrey Friedl (page 271):

```
sub parse_csv {
    my $text = shift; # record containing comma-separated values
    my @fields = ( );
    my $field;
 
    chomp($text);

    while ($text =~ m{\G(?:^|,)(?:"((?>[^"]*)(?:""[^"]*)*)"|([^",]*))}gx) {
        if (defined $2) {
            $field = $2;
        } else {
            $field = $1;
            $field =~ s/""/"/g;
        }
#        print "[$field]";
        push @fields, $field;
    }
    return @fields;
}
```

Try it against test row:

```
    my $line = q(Ten Thousand,10000, 2710 ,,"10,000",,"It's ""10 Grand"", baby",10K);
    my @fields = parse_csv($line);
    my $i;

    for ($i = 0; $i < @fields; $i++) {
         print "$fields[$i],";
    }
    print "\n";
```